# Select a value based on multiple rows in MySql

Tags: mysql, select

If I have the following example table:

```
id   docId   tagId
1     12      2
2     13      2
3     13      3
4     13      4
5     14      3
```

How can I select the *docId* where the *tagId* is both 2 and 3, i.e. docId = 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select docId
    from YourTable
    where tagId in (2,3)
    group by DocId
    having count(distinct tagId) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `(docId, tagId)` combination is unique:

```
SELECT  docId
FROM    mytable
WHERE   tagId IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY
        docId
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT docId
FROM my_table
WHERE tagId >= 2
AND tagId <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

use **Self Join**.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.docId 
    FROM test AS t1 
    INNER JOIN test AS t2
    ON (t1.docId = t2.docId and t1.tagId =2 AND t2.tagId =3)
```